# Is it possible to preview changes or add model versioning with KeystoneJS?

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

Let's take the Demo site for example: http://demo.keystonejs.com/keystone/posts

After creating a post, I was wondering if there's a way to enable versioning? Perhaps a way to specify which version to publish and also a way to preview new changes?

This is the use case:

1) User A publishes a Post

2) User B wants to change the copy

3) User A makes the changes but does not publish, but wants to send a preview link to User B

4) User B approves changes

5) User A creates new version and publishes it live

Comment: This is my first question on StackOverflow. Instead of down voting, please let me know what I'm incorrectly asking.

Comment: don't know what the downvote was for. This is functionality you have to add yourself. Use JS-fu.